# How to update one NumPy array with values from a different array?

Tags: python, numpy

If I had two different arrays with different dimensions like the following:

```
loaded_data = np.arange(4674).reshape(57, 41, 2)
final_data = np.zeros((60, 41, 2))
```

How would I most efficiently update final_data with the values from Loaded_data leaving the additional columns with zero value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array slicing to do the update

```
final_data[:loaded_data.shape[0]] = loaded_data
```